# Better way to perform sql query than using two forms on same page

Tags: php, sql

My users have some books.

Books are put in different categories, and inside the main categories there are subcategories.

I want to let the user be able to see a display o the books from the chosen main category, this is working fine at the moment by using a simple action form.
However I want the user to be able to access a sub category as well after the user has selected a main category.

I have problem with the user being able to access the subcategory, because if I make a second action form for the sub category, since all of this has to be viewed on the same page, the second action form interferes with first one.

Here is a snippet of my action form

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcats)) {
    $jada = $row['category'];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultfag)) {

        echo '<div class="categories">';

        echo ' <button class="fagbutton" name="fag-submitted" value="'.$row['name'].'"'.$row['name'].'>'.$row['name'].'</button><br>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

?>


</form>
```

I then use something like this to get a variable for my sql search query to show specific books under the clicked category.

```
if(isset($_POST['fag-submitted'])) {
    $fag = $_POST["fag-submitted"];
```

I do not have the code of my second action form I tried, I ended up deleting it as it does not work because it interferes with my first action form since it is all on the same page. But what I have tried so far is exactly that; a second action form for the sub categories.

To summarise;

My user clicks on a main category - that works fine using my shown action form. 
My user then gets the option to choose a sub category. This does not work. I can't make this to work with an action form because I'm already using one action form on the page for the main category. 
All this has to be done on the same page.

Comment: Quite simply AJAX

Comment: I did try to look into that, do you have a keyword of what my above problem is "about". So I can search the web better, as I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Once you do a little reseach on AJAX in general and the mechanism of AJAX the solution should become obvious

Comment: Alright, hopefully I'll be back to answer this with AJAX then. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be using AJAX.

For my particular problem this is the code I came up with that solved my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#categories .catbutton').each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(){
var category = $("#catbutton").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "demo.php",
  data: category,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
$("#display").html(result);
}
});

return false;

});
});
});
```